# gitignored file to Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I am a rails developer and trying to get familiar with Heroku.

I don't add config/environment.rb to git as environment.rb might be different for each environment.
For example, ENV['RAILS_ENV'] = 'some_env' should be in environment.rb.

However, Heroku requires environment.rb to be in git so that I can push it to Heroku.

Is there a way to just copy environment.rb to Heroku without version-controlling it?

Thanks.

Sam

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You always want to keep the environment.rb file checked in. You can set the environment using config variables

`heroku config:add RAILS_ENV=some_env`

So you store your config with each individual app. You can read any config variables from your application by using ENV[]

Comment: My designer works on other hosting and we set ENV['RAILS_ENV'] = 'design' in config/environment.rb. So environment.rb might be different for each developer. Thus I don't check-in the file to git.

Comment: You can't do it that way if you want to use Heroku. It is very important that you track all your code in version control (http://www.12factor.net/codebase) and that any config that varries from machine to machine is stored in the environment(http://www.12factor.net/config) you can use foreman on development computers https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars#local-setup.